# functions that f(n) is not O(g(n)) and g(n) is not O(f(n))

Tags: algorithm

Are there any functions such as f(n) and g(n) that both;

```
f(n) != O(g(n)) and
g(n) != O(f(n)).
```

Are there any functions that fulfills the requirements at the above?

Comment: Is this a homework assignment?

Comment: no I was just reviewing the algorithms, and it got stuck on my mind.

Comment: It is for me. I've been thinking about how this is possible for hours.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 f(n)=n and g(n)=n^(1 + sin(x)).
```

f(n) is not O(g(n)) and g(n) is not O(f(n)).

Refer http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?BigOh

Comment: but you have 2 variables n x here

Answer (score 1):

Consider:

```
f(n) = 0 if n is odd, else n*n
g(n) = n
```

Then for odd values `g(n)` is more than a constant factor bigger than `f(n)` (and so `g(n)` is not `O(f(n))`, while for even values `f(n)` is more than a constant factor bigger than `g(n)` (and so `f(n)` is not `O(g(n))`).

Observe that `f(n)` does not have a limit at infinity as `n` approaches infinity, so in some sense this is a cheap example. But you could fix that by replacing `0,  n,  n*n` with `n, n*n, n*n*n`.

I think if two non-negative functions have the property that `f(n)/g(n)` has a (perhaps infinite) limit as `n` approaches infinity, then it follows that one of them is big-O the other one. If the limit is 0 then `f(n)` is `O(g(n))`, if the limit is finite then each is big-O the other, and if the limit is infinite then `g(n)` is `O(f(n))`. But I'm too lazy to confirm by writing a proof.

Comment: Loosely speaking, if one of the functions is not monotonically increasing, but is still asymptotically larger than the other on a subset of their domains, you've found a pair of functions that satisfy the property in question.

Comment: The proof is easy: for `f(n)` being `O(g(n))`, it should exists a fixed costant `c` such that `f(n) <= c g(n)` for every `n > n_0`, thus `f(n) / g(n) <= c`.

Comment: @akappa: that is an easy proof, but it doesn't prove my claim. You have proved that X => Y, my claim is that Y => (X or some other possibilities). The proof I need will have about as little arithmetic as yours, but it needs to consider several cases.

Comment: Well, if the limit is finite, then `g(n) / f(n) <= 1/c`, and your claim on one being big-Oh of the other follows; if the limit is zero, then for each \epsilon it exists n_0 such that, for all n \geq n_0, f(n)/g(n) \leq \epsilon, thus (picking any \epsilon > 0), f(n) \leq \epsilon g(n) for n >= n_0, and your claim follows. A similar argument holds for the infinity case.